# Spring 4 and jersey 2 integration without bean autowiring

Tags: spring, jersey, autowired

I want to ask that is there a way to use spring 4 and jersey 2 integration without auto wiring.I have a requirement that for dependency injection I should be using setter methods(no @Autowired annotation) and configure beans in spring configuration file.Our project is using spring 4 and jersey 2.I googled a lot for this requirement but did not get any success,everywhere I found the usage of @Autowired.Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This might work for you: https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b32/spring-bridge.html

Comment: thanks, its really helpful